Number of paths to go from (0,0) to (6,4), each step can only be one up or to the right, and no three consecutive steps in the same direction?
here is a question I encountered in a quant trading interview. I did not find a way to count cases with three consecutive steps that are not too messy. How to approach this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please edit the question to add your thoughts on how to solve the problem.  You received a close vote (and will probably receive more) because your post shows no evidence of an independent effort to reach a solution.  Please be sure to edit the question rather than adding your efforts in a comment.  This is not too difficult to solve if approached as a stars-and-bars problem with constraints.

@RobertShore I am curious to hear what approach you have in mind. The approach described in Vlad Boiko's answer would, I imagine, count as "messy" in the sense used by OP (and not productive in terms of a general solution when $(6,4)$ is replaced by some arbitrary $(n,k)$).

Probably, there is a simpler solution, but it is the first one, which I came up with:
there is a bijection between any way you can get from $(0;0)$ to $(6;4)$ and between number of ways to arrange $4$ bars between $6$ stars in the way, that there are no $3$ consecutive stars nor bars. This, in turn, is the same number of ways as there are ways to divide $6$ into $5$ terms, which are more or equal to $0$, where no $2$ consecutive terms are $0$, and every term is less or equal to $2$.
Note, that there is no partition of $6$, which satisfies all those properties and has more than $3$ zeros (sum of terms will be less than $6$), so let's consider cases, when number of $0$s is $0$,$1$,$2$.
Firstly, if there are $2$ zeros, then every other term is $2$. Then the number of partitions is ($5$ $2$)$ - 4= 10-4=6$. ($10$ partitions satisfy that there are $2$ zeros and $3$ twos, then if $2$ zeros are consecutive, there are $4$ cases to exclude)
Secondly, if there is only $1$ zero, then other terms are $1, 1, 2, 2$ in some order. In this case, $2$ zeros can't be consecutive, so the number of partitions is $5!/(2!*2!) = 30$.
Lastly, if there are no zeros, then any partition with terms $1, 1, 1, 1, 2$ will satisfy. There are $5$ of those.
Overall, it seems that there are $41$ distinct solutions, correct me if I'm wrong.

Welcome to MathSE.  Please refrain from answering questions that do not meet quality standards.

There are actually 43 paths.
